# Simple C++ program builds ok in CMake with Debug Config, but fails with release

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I have this simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::cout << "Hello Build Type!" << std::endl;
   std::cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

I can build it with no issues using CMake command:
`cmake --build .`

with CmakeLists.txt being this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES DEBUG)

project (build_type CXX)
add_executable(cmake_examples_build_type main.cpp)
```

However, when I change `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` to `RELEASE`, I get this error when I build with `cmake --build .`

> Build started 10/24/2018 10:35:38 AM.
>   Project "C:\Users\ialkeilani\OneDrive - Ushrauto\temp\cmake-examples-master\01-basic\F-build-type\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
>   Project "C:\Users\ialkeilani\OneDrive - Ushrauto\temp\cmake-examples-master\01-basic\F-build-type\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building
>    "C:\Users\ialkeilani\OneDrive
>    - Ushrauto\temp\cmake-examples-master\01-basic\F-build-type\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(61,5):  error MSB8013: This project doesn't contain the Configuration and Platform
>   combination of Debug|Win32. [C:\Users\ialkeilani\OneDrive - Ushrauto\temp\cmake-examples-master\01-basic\F-build-type\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]
>   Done Building Project "C:\Users\ialkeilani\OneDrive - Ushrauto\temp\cmake-examples-master\01-basic\F-build-type\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Done Building Project "C:\Users\ialkeilani\OneDrive - Ushrauto\temp\cmake-examples-master\01-basic\F-build-type\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "C:\Users\ialkeilani\OneDrive - Ushrauto\temp\cmake-examples-master\01-basic\F-build-type\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
>   "C:\Users\ialkeilani\OneDrive - Ushrauto\temp\cmake-examples-master\01-basic\F-build-type\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
>   (PlatformPrepareForBuild target) ->
>     C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(61,5): error MSB8013: This project doesn't contain the Configuration and Platfor
>   m combination of Debug|Win32. [C:\Users\ialkeilani\OneDrive - Ushrauto\temp\cmake-examples-master\01-basic\F-build-type\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]
>
> 0 Warning(s)
>       1 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.18

Moreover, when I attempt to build using MSVC with this command:
`msbuild build_type.sln /p:configuration=release`

build finishes ok with no issues.

Can someone please enlighten me as to why is CMake is failing to build the release configuration while MSVC has no issues?

Running MS Visual Studio 2013 and CMake 3.5.2

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is a "multi configurations" generator, hence:

Setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` has no effect. You can verify this by opening the generated solution: All configurations are still available.

Setting `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=Release` is the correct way: Opening the generated solution in the IDE will only allow you to select the "Release" configuration. Building you example will work just fine from within the Visual Studio IDE.

However there seems to be a bug in CMake in combination with Visual Studio Generator when running `cmake --build .` Changing the command to `cmake --build . --config Release` will work. This seems to be a regression in CMake, as this used to work at some point. I ran into this specific issue myself after recently upgrading my build environment.

Btw this really seems to be only happening with Visual Studio. I didn't see this problem with XCode, which is also a "multi configurations" generator.

Answer (score -1):

You should use below option instead of CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES:

```
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE
```

This can be set either through cmake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug <cmake-source-tree>
```

or by using ccmake:

```
ccmake <cmake-source-tree>
```

[image]

Note that you need to configure first (as shown above) and then do the build step. That is:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<Release|Debug> <cmake-source-tree>
make
```

. if you do your build in your project path, but consider using out-of-source build as proposed by CMake.

Comment: For multi-configuration generators, like Visual Studio, setting `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` variable is perfectly valid. As opposite, setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` for such generator is rarely used.

Comment: correct since i'm on visual studio I used CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPE. I tried CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE, project builds ok but the executable is still placed in the debug folder.  Same result when I empty the build directory and start from scratch?